# Best way to show blank cell if value if zero

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

```
=COUNTIFS(Orders!$T:$T,$B4)
```

is a code that gives 0 or a +ve result

I use this across 1500 cells which makes the sheet gets filled with 0s

I'd like to remove the Zeros by using the following formula

```
if(COUNTIFS(Orders!$T:$T,$B3,Orders!$F:$F,""&P$1&"*")=0,
"",
COUNTIFS(Orders!$T:$T,$B3,Orders!$F:$F,""&P$1&"*"))
```

This calculates every formula twice and increases the calculation time.

How can we do this in 1 formula where if the value is 0 - keep empty - otherwise display the answer

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: If cell equals 0, then leave it blank
But with least calculations

Comment: Add conditional formatting?

Answer (score 9):

You only need to set the number format for your range of cells.

Go to the menu `Format-->Number-->More Formats-->Custom Number Format...`

In the entry area at the top, enter the following:  `#;-#;""`

The "format" of the format string is

> (positive value format) ; (negative value format) ; (zero value format)

You can apply colors or commas or anything else. See [this link](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) for details

Comment: Is there no equation based formula ... something like what iferror would do for error values - here we need it for "0" values

Answer (score 9):

I suggest this cell-function:

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/COUNTIFS(Orders!$T:$T,$B4)))
```

EDIT:
I'm not sure what to add as explanation. Basically to replace the result of a complex calculation with blank cells if it results in 0, you can wrap the complex function in

```
IFERROR(1/(1/  ComplexFunction()   ))
```

It works by twice taking the inverse (1/X) of the result, thus returning the original result in all cases except 0 where a DIV0 error is generated. This error is then caught by IFERROR to result in a blank cell.

The advantage of this method is that it doesn't need to calculate the complex function twice, so can give a significant speed/readability increase, and doesn't fool the output like a custom number format which can be important if this cell is used in further functions.

Comment: Downvotes not by me, but I recommend to improve your code-only answer by adding some explanation. That would also help fighting the misunderstanding that StackOverflow is a free code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

instead of your `=COUNTIFS(Orders!$T:$T,$B4)` use:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(""&COUNTIFS(Orders!$T:$T,$B4), "^0$", )
```

also, to speed up things you should avoid "per row formulae" and use ArrayFormulas

Comment: REGEXREPLACE returns a string. If OP wants to keep cell contents as numbers they must use VALUE(), and VALUE("") will return 0.