# Is it possible to leave the cell empty when the value is zero where dayOfWeek?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

You can leave the empty cell with no value when the value is zero? using the function:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(N(REGEXMATCH(""&TRIM(SPLIT(QUERY({JANEIRO!A$2:C; FEVEREIRO!A$2:C}; 
 "select Col1 where dayOfWeek(Col3) = 3"; 2); ",")); "^"&TO_TEXT(A2)&"$"))))
```

Link to help understand: [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tYwxpvRyqqq9ol_oUoMaBgseVFTdp9ANS72AaBJDiiY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Refer [Best way to show blank cell if value if zero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49522011/1330560), particularly the answer dealing with number formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this instead:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(""&SUM(N(REGEXMATCH(""&TRIM(SPLIT(
 QUERY({JANEIRO!A$2:C; FEVEREIRO!A$2:C}; 
 "select Col1 where dayOfWeek(Col3) = 3"; 2); ",")); "^"&TO_TEXT(A2)&"$"))); "^0$"; ))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

You can use IF function. Example :

```
=if(B7=0;"";"not blank")
```

Let's say you write this formula in cell C7. C7 will be blank/empty if B7 is 0.

Comment: How would this apply to the OP's formula?

Comment: He can wrap-up SUM under IF.

Comment: I understand, but you can deploy within the function: = ARRAYFORMULA (SUM (N (REGEXMATCH ("" & TRIM (SPLIT (QUERY ({JANUARY! A $ 2: C; FEBRUARY! A $ 2: C};
  "select Col1 where dayOfWeek (Col3) = 3"; 2); ",")); "^" & TO_TEXT (A2) & "$")))))