# Google Sheets: ArrayFormula sumifs, but return some symbol or empty cell if there's nothing to sum

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, sumifs

I have the following table:

                                                                             `Jan`        `Feb`        `Mar`
                                                                              `P7`          `Q7`         `R7`
                                                                            56.80           0             0
         `Column E    Column I    Column N`

17       expense         Jan-5            15.87

18            $               Jan-9            56.80

19       expense        Feb-8            38.12

20       expense        Mar 5            45.38

21            $              Mar-12            0.00

So I have 
 `Cell P7` with the following formula `=ArrayFormula(sumifs(N17:N,E17:E,"$",MONTH(I17:I),1))`
and 
`Cell Q7` with the following formula 
`=ArrayFormula(sumifs(N17:N,E17:E,"$",MONTH(I17:I),2))` 
 
and 
`Cell R7` with the following formula 
`=ArrayFormula(sumifs(N17:N,E17:E,"$",MONTH(I17:I),3))` 
that checks `Column I` for January dates (for `P7`), February dates (for `Q7`) and March dates (for `R7`), then checks if there's at least one sign `$` in corresponding `Column E` for those dates, and if there is, sums all corresponding amounts in `Column N`. 

Now, my problem is this: the formula, as it is now, returns `0` even if there are no signs `$` for a specific month range, like for February in the above table. There are no `$` sign in `Column E` for February, yet cell `Q7` shows `0`.

I would like it to:

- return nothing at all (empty cell instead of `0`) if there are no amounts in `Column N` for a specific month marked with `$` sign in `Column E` 

- return `0` only if there is `0.00` amount in `Column N` along with the `$` sign in corresponding `Column E`.

or

- return something else, like `~`, if there's nothing to sum up.

Let's say for March I could put `$` in `E21` and `~` in `N21` and see that `~` returned in `R7` if there are no more amounts to sum up.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Here's a blank sample sheet.  try pasting some stuff there to illustrate your question.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/112dRSNPt_hyq5qr6JoumHSCqALrY7o2klR4IHi_NqoI/edit

Comment: Did that. Hopefully now it will be easier to understand what I want :-)

Comment: I believe this question is asked and answered already.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49521564/best-way-to-show-blank-cell-if-value-if-zero

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to MAttKing's [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49521564/best-way-to-show-blank-cell-if-value-if-zero), simply add your formula in `IFERROR(1/(1/  ComplexFunction()   ))` which should look something like this.

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/ArrayFormula(sumifs(D3:D,A3:A,"$",MONTH(B3:B),2))))
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Hello! And thanks for your help!

Comment: The problem with your formula is that it returns an empty cell in any condition: whether there is no payments during any given month (no $ signs in Column A) or there is a $ sign in Column A with either 0 or let's say ~ sign in corresponding cell in Month Column. In other words I will have no means to tell whether a payment was required or it wasn't. Say I look at cell D2 and I see 0 as it was before or an empty cell as it became with your formula, I have no idea whether I checked already that the payment wasn't required and that's why the cell D2 is 0 or empty or I still need to check.

Comment: And if I were able to get the formula that would return me an empty cell when there's no $ signs in Column A and cell with 0 or some other symbol (like ~) when I'd put $ sign in Column A and either 0 or some other symbol (like ~) in corresponding cell in Month Column (let's say Column D), I would definitely know that in first case I'd still need to check if payment's required and in second case I'd know that I already checked and confirmed that payment hadn't been required.