# Google Sheets: ArrayFormula sumifs (with IFERROR). How to add an extra criteria?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, countif, sumifs

I have the following perfectly working formula:
`=IFERROR(1/(1/ArrayFormula(sumifs(G34:G,$E34:$E,"$",MONTH($B34:$B),1))))`

It serves the needs explained in
[my previously asked question][1]

All I want is to add an extra criteria to that formula so instead of checking just `$E34:$E` for the `"$"` value, it would check `$E34:$E` and, say, `$F34:$F` for the `"$"` value and `SUMIF` only if the `"$"` is found in both `$E34:$E` and `$F34:$F` ranges. And `DO NOT SUM` if the `"$"` value is only found in one of the ranges or no range at all. 
I've already tried:
`=IFERROR(1/(1/ArrayFormula(sumifs(G34:G,$E34:$E&$F34:$F,"$",MONTH($B34:$B),1))))`

`=IFERROR(1/(1/ArrayFormula(sumifs(G34:G,(IF(MMULT(($E34:$E,"$")*($F34:$F,"$")))))),MONTH($B34:$B),1))`

No luck :-(

[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71207513/google-sheets-arrayformula-sumifs-but-return-some-symbol-or-empty-cell-if-ther

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add it as a third condition and not trying to combine those two columns in one. They'll be summed only if the three conditions are met.

Try this:

> =IFERROR(1/(1/ArrayFormula(sumifs(G34:G,$E34:$E,"$",$F34:$F,"$",MONTH($B34:$B),1))))